# how to find a Column Name by database column name in grid view in c#

Tags: c#

I want to find a column name by bind Database column name
can anyone help me how to achieve this functionality

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ref Doc#">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("poNo")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="textAlignCenter noWrap" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="textAlignCenter noWrap" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ref Date">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("poDate", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSum" runat="server" Text="Total Amount:" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="textAlignCenter noWrap" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="textAlignCenter noWrap" />
    <FooterStyle CssClass="textAlignLeft" />
</asp:TemplateField>   

protected void grdOutstandingInvoice_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I want to find column index by Eval("poNo"), how we can achieve this.
please help me.

thanks in Advance

Comment: So you want to find out the column index or column name?

Comment: I want to find column index and then i want to visible = false